# Clipping polygon layer into multiple polygons via model builder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, modelbuilder, clip

I have a huge polygon layer created from a raster, and over that I have a watershed shapefile. I need to run a land-use regression process on each individual watershed so I'd like to clip and export each watershed's polygon layer to its own layer. Can this be done through the model builder so I don't have to sit around and reset the geoprocessor for every watershed? i am using ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 4):

Set up your model as shown below

[image]

- Use [Iterate Feature Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Iterate_Feature_Selection/00400000000s000000/) in your model
- Use the watershed name/id field as **group by field**
- Use **Value** in the clip tool as part of the output name. %Value%
- **Value** contains the name/id of the watershed.

Comment: My "Iterate Feature Selection" does not give me two inputs. How does the "Group by fields" module get generated? I'm sure there will be more questions but lets just start with that

Comment: right click on Iterate Feature Selection, navigate to Make Variable>From Parameter>Group By Fields.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the **[Split tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000006000000)** in data management did exactly what I wanted.